# Insert label data from DataList into database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, webforms

I am using a DataBind to display images into DataList. Each of image have a button for voting.

My button to vote :

```
<asp:Image ID="imgFavBefore" runat="server" CssClass="voteStyle" ImageUrl="~/Img Content/love.png" Style="height: 20px; width: 20px; align-content: center;" CommandName="btnFavBefore" data-index="<%#Container.ItemIndex %>" />
```

And a label to display the total of the upvote when button vote clicked :

```
<asp:Label ID="lblVote" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("likes")%>' CssClass="lblVoteStyle" data-index="<%#Container.ItemIndex %>" data-count="0" />
```

All label count is start from 0. So what I'm trying to do here is, I want to directly save the count of the upvote inside database first before the count will be displayed back in label refer to which image it belonged to.

Kindly to help me. Thank you.

**EDIT :**

I set my DataList like this :

```
<asp:DataList Width="100%" ItemStyle-horizontalalign="center" ItemStyle-Width="200px" ID="imgDataList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" OnItemCommand="imgDataList_ItemCommand">
```

Then I tried to access the button using the **OnItemCommand** of my DataList :

```
Protected Sub imgDataList_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As DataListCommandEventArgs)
        If e.CommandName = "btnFavBefore" Then
            ' some code here
        End If
    End Sub
```

The problem here is, my coding didn't go through **imgDataList_ItemCommand**

Comment: try first and revert back with issue you are facing in code. No one is going to start it for you

Comment: I already try it myself. Adding `OnItemCommand="imgDataList_ItemCommand"` to get access of the button inside the DataList, adding a method to add up the vote which is directly inserted into database, but my coding didn't go through the method. Means that my web unable to read the `OnItemCommand` of DataList. That's why I'm trying to get help here.

Comment: You should paste that code too

Comment: @Anonymous I've been updated my question. Do you have any idea? Thanks.